# How to show 0 at the begining in hexadecimal with bash printf cmd

Tags: bash, shell, printf

I need to create a script to calculate addresses Mac.

The problem is when I display the result, if the the Mac address begin with "0" ,

Example :

> for 08952A421DE8
>
> It show 8952A421DE8

My printf is :

```
printf "NAME %s MACADDRESS \n" "${clientid[$i]}" "$((0x${mac[$i]}))"
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make bash aware that this is a hex number with a fixed number of digits.  Currently it only is an arbitrary string.

Try this:

```
printf "NAME %s MACADDRESS %012x\n" "${clientid[$i]}" "0x${mac[$i]}"
```

With `%012x` you specify the format for 12 hex digits with leading zeros if necessary.

`printf` will interpret the `0x` prefix itself, so no need to use `$((…))` in this case.